# Strange error: after create user alway redirects ot show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

It is strange. I'm writing custom user registration and want to make redirection to OTHER page after user creation, but it want to call show action.

Here is my controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_verify_path }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }

  end
end
```

end
    def verify
     ...
     end
in routes.rb:

```
       resources :users

       root :to => 'users#new'

        get "users/verify"
```

when I rename action into SHOW everything is working. If I name it VERIFY - it shows me:

```
    Unknown action

    The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController
```

it is obvious error, because I deleted action show. But WHY it is redirecting to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write get "users/verify" before resources :users

or

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'verify'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, it is working. Thanks. Can you explain why it is working like that ?

Comment: Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :users above a get 'users/verify' the show action’s route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. It`s from rails docs.

Comment: Can you suggest reason of my next error ? When I try to use `def verify
   @user = User.find(params[:id])` shows me error - `Couldn't find User without an ID`

Comment: I need to use user data to in this action.

Comment: Try to use member inside resources users, as i wrote it in my answer above, then id shoul be in url and params[:id]

Comment: Can you look here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195775/how-use-data-related-to-object-which-im-not-saving-to-database ?