# How use data related to object which I'm not saving to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I need to use User data, which he is entering in form, but not save it.

I added attribute accessors into my User model:

```
   attr_accessible :paypal_email, :first_name, :last_name
   attr_accessor :first_name
   attr_accessor :last_name
```

but how can I use it after user submits form? I need to verify account details, but didn't save them, so I need to use in controller

```
 @user.first_name and @user.last_name
```

**My verification action:**

```
   def verify

 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
 require 'httpclient'
 require 'xmlsimple'

 clnt = HTTPClient.new

header =  {"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" => "№№№№№№№№",
               "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" => "333333333",
               "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" => "3333333333",
               "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" => "NV",
               "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" => "XML",
               "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" =>  "APP-2J632856DC989803F"
                }

data = {"emailAddress" => @user.paypal_email,
       "firstName"=> @user.first_name,
       "lastName" => @user.last_name,
       "matchCriteria" => "NAME",         
       "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US"}

 uri = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"
 res = clnt.post(uri, data, header)
  @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)

 if res.status == 200
    if @xml['accountStatus']!=nil
      account_status = @xml['accountStatus'][0]
      if account_status == "VERIFIED" 
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:success] = "Your account is verified"
      else 
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:error] = res.content
      end

    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:error] = res.content
  end  
  else 
    flash[:error] = "Oops! Can't conntect to PayPal"
end

end
```

and error:

```
   Invalid request parameter: lastName</message><parameter>lastName
```

how I can do that ?

Comment: The code you pasted should work already. Do you get any errors while doing this?

Comment: @Waseem , I will show you my code and response what I get.

Comment: @Waseem, I think it is not sending lastName

Comment: Okay first make sure that the `@user.last_name` is indeed present there. Add a debugger or a logger.info before preparing the data hash and check the value of `@user.first_name`. If it is present, which I think is, consult the Paypal API what it expects in lastName parameter.

Comment: @Waseem, where I should add logger.info ? I didn't use it before.

Comment: `logger.info(@user.first_name)` ?

Comment: Yes. Dude come to #RubyOnRails channel on Freenode IRC. You could get this answered fast.

Comment: @Waseem, I can't see anything in my development log file. I see only that request is processed

Comment: @Waseem, can you give me a link ?

Comment: Follow something like http://www.zantherus.com/community/topic/2635-howto-connect-to-irc-with-pidgin/

Comment: @Waseem, I have another question - how can I implement before_save filter ? I mean to call verify before_save

Comment: Follow http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Comment: There are examples only on validation, and no on before_save filter. Can I update my question and you look at my code ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should go for form_tag. form_tag is used to upload details that are not associated with any model object.

Comment: and I will be able to use data ? Can you give example ?

Comment: Can I use it in before_save filter ?

Comment: save filter is code in the model, where as form submission hits controller action. What you need is to build your model object from params data and save it. It will behaves normally like any other save with executing all filters that are applied.

Comment: Can you look here and say what I'm doing wrong ? I should use `params[:user][:first_name]` ?

Comment: I would suggest you to check your web log for this and find how the parameters are passing to action via params

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if I understand your question correctly.

You want first_name and last_name data to be verified which is entered by Form (HTML) page.

Let us say, you have given names of respective input fields in html forms as form_first_name and form_last_name.

You can simply access them by using params[:form_first_name] and params[:form_last_name] respectively inside your controller.